# Good value laptop for home office use at around £500

Tags: laptop

In the market for a new laptop to replace my aged machine. As I understand it, at this price range and requirements. I'm probably best off going for an i3 processor.

Requirements:
- 8GB RAM
- An SSD to run the operating system
- A large (750GB plus) standard HDD for storage
- Windows 10

Most of the models in this price range come with 4GB RAM which seems woefully insufficient to me. Many also offer only one drive, instead of separate SSD and HDD.

Nice-to-have:
- Fairly portable (light, with good battery time)
- Basic gaming & image editing performance

I don't want a 2-in-1 tablet-style machine - I'd want something larger and more robust than that.

Answer (score 2):

I think this Acer laptop is worth a look:

**https://www.amazon.co.uk/F5-573G-Notebook-NX-GDAEK-003-Dedicated-Graphics/dp/B06XKBCSSJ**

Basically ticks all your - very clearly - defined checkboxes. And although Acer is not considered the best manufacturer, being on this budget I don't see anything better for your needs.

- 15.6" Full HD Screen
- List item
- Intel Core i3-6100
- 8GB RAM 128G SSD + 1TB HDD
- Dedicated GeForce GTX 950M 4GB Graphics